# Accessing Error Detail in Console

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-el

Using Mule 4.1

When an error is encountered in a flow something like the following is logged in the console.

> ********************************************************************************
>  Message               : Cannot parse input XML because it is
>   invalid.
>  Error type            : XML-MODULE:INVALID_INPUT_XML
>   Element               : LogError/processors/0/processors/0 @
>   systemadapter:systemadapter.xml:29 (Validate schema)
>  Element XML  
>   : 
>   
>     (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for
>   everything)
>   ********************************************************************************

I know how to access the Message and the Error Type.  How do I get the Element or Element XML?  I've used the below Data-weave to to get the error information.  However, I cannot seem to find any thing that will tell the Element. My over all goal would be to find which component in the flow generated the error.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "message" : error.exception.message,
    "detailMessage" : error.exception.detailMessage,
    "identifier" : error.errorType.identifier,
    "namespace" : error.errorType.namespace,
    "detailedDescription" : error.detailedDescription,
    "causeMessage" : error.exception.cause.message,
    "causeDetailMessage" : error.exception.cause.detailMessage,
    "backtrace" : error.exception.cause.backtrace

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from the MuleSoft support team I was able to access the detail using `#[message.message.exceptionPayload.info]` This returns an array of objects that are presented in the console.  So, my Dataweve needs to look like the following.  I've only verified this in Mule 4.1.2 and 4.1.3.

```
%dw 2.0 output application/json
--- {
    "message" : error.exception.message,
    "detailMessage" : error.exception.detailMessage,
    "element" : message.message.exceptionPayload.info['Element'],
    "elementXML" : message.message.exceptionPayload.info['Element XML']
}
```